# Is there a way to cast between an interface and its specialization in JAVA?

Tags: java, oop, interface

I have these three interfaces in my code:

```java
public interface ParentInterface {
  // some properties and methods
}
public interface ChildOne extends ParentInterface{
  //some extra properties and methods
}
public interface ChildTwo extends ParentInterface{
  //some extra properties and methods
}
```

I have some function `void someFunc(List<ParentInterface>)`, which should be able to accept hybrid lists with instances implementing either `ChildOne` or `ChildTwo`. But what if I have a `List<ChildOne>` ? is there a better way to call `someFunc` than this one ?

```java
List<ChildOne> coList = new HashList<ChildOne>();
//add some items to coList
List<ParentInterface> piList = new HashList<ParentInterface>(coList.size());
piList.addAll(coList);
someFunc(piList);
```

Can't I just make the call like this `someFunc(coList)` without having to create a new list ?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p) helps

Comment: Sounds like you want to make your method accept `List<? extends ParentInterface>`...

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks dude, that works like a charm !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jon Skeet suggested in a comment, I changed the signature of my function to become `void someFunc(List<? extends ParentInterface>)` and that worked like a charm !